# "Rolled up" notifications triggers onNotificationRemoved in NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, notifications

Not sure about the proper term for this, but sometimes when an app posts multiple notifications, the subsequent notifications are rolled up into the first one. Example will be

```
Notification 1
Contact 1: Hello!
```

Then when another notification comes in (e.g. Contact 2: Hey!):

```
You have 2 notifications from User 1 and User 2.
```

I am writing a notification listener service that manages notifications posted by other apps. I opt for the 4.3 NotificationListener service because that's what Google recommends over accessibility services.
My idea is when the notification of the apps are cleared by the user, onNotificationRemoved will be triggered and I can clear the managed notifications with my service accordingly.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.some.app.im.monitoring")) {
        // some code that updates the notification state for this app
    }
}
```

The problem I have right now is when the "roll up" happens, the incoming notification is cleared by the app itself and rolled up with other notifications it received. This triggers onNotificationRemoved for the incoming notification, and there is no way for me to know whether it is triggered by user or by the roll up.
How can I avoid this getting trigger by the roll up?

Comment: There's no way to distinguish those cases (the user dismissed a notification vs. the app withdrew it), unfortunately.

What are you trying to do that you need to know this?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I am just now searching for a smart solution to solve this. If you have anything, please post it here.